# Recursive query to get totals by distinct item from a row of a data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL data that looks like the following:

```
ResultId    HomeTeam    HomeScore   AwayTeam    AwayScore
1045        USA         2           France      3
1046        USA         1           Botswana    1
1047        Botswana    2           France      2
```

How can I recurse through this data to get total wins, draws, losses by team for both home and away?  My output would look something like:

```
Team        Wins        Draws      Losses
USA         0           1          1
France      1           1          0
Botswana    0           2          0
```

I was able to get this done in a very linear way by simply get a list of distinct teams and for each team looping through the data and tallying the win, draw, loss total and aggregating that into variables. However, I imagine there may be a different way to accomplish this.

Comment: What happened to DRC, they had 1 draw? Botswana had 1 draw not 2?

Comment: @Dale, I had done this in javascript on my front end.  I was hoping to do the same directly in sql and wanted to know the best way to accomplish it.  I'm fine with whatever explanations and guides you have to offer as opposed to an actual implementation.

Comment: @Charlieface, good catch I made an edit to make it just Botswana and no DRC.

Comment: Thats not how this site works. You need to first do your research, have a go (using the desired technology), and then post a question when stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need recursion here, you can just unpivot the Home and Away sides, then group by the `Team` and do conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  v.Team,
  Wins   = COUNT(CASE WHEN ScoreDiff > 0 THEN 1 END),
  Draws  = COUNT(CASE WHEN ScoreDiff = 0 THEN 1 END),
  Losses = COUNT(CASE WHEN ScoreDiff < 0 THEN 1 END) 
FROM Matches
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (HomeTeam, HomeScore - AwayScore),
    (AwayTeam, AwayScore - HomeScore)
) v(Team, ScoreDiff)
GROUP BY
  v.Team;
```

| Team | Wins | Draws | Losses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Botswana | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| DRC | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| France | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| USA | 0 | 1 | 1 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ca5e9328b59eb204ecdc50217065237)

Comment: Interesting use of a lateral query here. I wonder if the performance is comparable to a subquery (that I would have used). I tend to think that lateral queries are slower, but maybe the engine is able to simplify it behind the scenes. +1 for the correctness and novelty

Comment: @Charlie Thanks, I was able to derive a solution based on the solution you suggest.   My original data did not have the home and away results aggregated so I ended up just using the option of just aggregating whatever stats I need directly from the home and away tables.

Comment: @TheImpaler Benefit of this kind of lateral query is that you only scan the table once. Whereas the benefit of doing it as two separate unioned queries is that you can use the indexes on each column

Comment: @Charlieface I was looking at the execution plan and it effectively scans the table once. It uses the `Constant Scan` operator that I haven't seen before. Great.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes it results in a `Nested Loop` against a two-row `Constant Scan` (completely normal for a `VALUES` virtual table), however it will need another sort to support the grouping. So it depends on your indexing

Answer (score 1):

There is a more straightforward solution by combining outputs of two queries using `Union All`, where the first query processes the results of matches for "HomeTeam", and the second for "AwayTeam".

```
Select Team, Sum(Wins), Sum(Draws), Sum(Losses)
From (
Select HomeTeam As Team,
       Sum(Iif(HomeScore>AwayScore, 1, 0)) As Wins,
       Sum(Iif(HomeScore=AwayScore, 1, 0)) As Draws,
       Sum(Iif(HomeScore<AwayScore, 1, 0)) As Losses
From Tbl
Group by HomeTeam
Union All
Select AwayTeam As Team,
       Sum(Iif(AwayScore>HomeScore, 1, 0)) As Wins,
       Sum(Iif(AwayScore=HomeScore, 1, 0)) As Draws,
       Sum(Iif(AwayScore<HomeScore, 1, 0)) As Losses
From Tbl
Group by AwayTeam) As T
Group By Team
Order by Team
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78be90e3315a6514d9a8ad7836392290), should work in most cases.

```
(select Matches.HomeTeam Team, 
sum(case when a.HomeResult='Win' Then 1 else 0 end) Win, 
sum(case when a.HomeResult='Loss' Then 1 else 0 end) Loss,
sum(case when a.HomeResult='Draw' Then 1 else 0 end) Draw
from 
(select ResultId, 
case
 when HomeScore>AwayScore then 'Win'
 when HomeScore=AwayScore then 'Draw'
 else 'Loss'
end as HomeResult,
case
 when HomeScore>AwayScore then 'Loss'
 when HomeScore=AwayScore then 'Draw'
 else 'Win'
end as AwayResult
from Matches) a join Matches on Matches.ResultId=a.ResultId group by HomeTeam)
Union
(select Matches.AwayTeam Team, 
sum(case when a.AwayResult='Win' Then 1 else 0 end) Win, 
sum(case when a.AwayResult='Loss' Then 1 else 0 end) Loss,
sum(case when a.AwayResult='Draw' Then 1 else 0 end) Draw 
from 
(select ResultId, 
case
 when HomeScore>AwayScore then 'Win'
 when HomeScore=AwayScore then 'Draw'
 else 'Loss'
end as HomeResult,
case
 when HomeScore>AwayScore then 'Loss'
 when HomeScore=AwayScore then 'Draw'
 else 'Win'
end as AwayResult
from Matches) a join Matches on Matches.ResultId=a.ResultId group by AwayTeam)
```